# Prevent scrolling in mobile using scrollable component

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to prevent the page from scrolling while dragging items from mobile devices?

Even the sortable demo page has this problem (if you load it from an android/iphone/ipad): http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/

Dragging sideways is less of an issue due to no scroll being necessary due to the width but vertical dragging is not working as I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty "brute force" and could limit your ability to drag an element to a position outside the current viewport, but adding a class with the style or directly adding the style of `overflow: hidden` to the `html` element while the item drag is active will prevent scrolling.

I've done this for modal windows to prevent the page in the back from scrolling while the modal is active.

Last time I used it a cross-browser issue required the use of `overflow: hidden !important` if it's not working for you.

Comment: Thank you, that works. A bit more brute force than I was hoping for. I just assumed I had missed something in the docs.